# How to use a lambda expression in a decorator?

Tags: python, lambda, syntax, decorator

I found this piece of interesting code online, however it throws a syntax error. How can I fix it?

```
@lambda _: _()
class _:
    def __format__(_, __):
        _.__class__._ = property(lambda _: print(__))
        return ""
def __() -> f"{_: Hello, world!}": ...
_._
```

Error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-17-773eeacca942>", line 1
    @lambda _: _()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you sure this is real? If so, check your python version maybe (wild guess)?

Comment: I get no error when I type it into the Python 3.9.2 REPL.

Comment: Thanks! I was using Python Python 3.7.13, just now tried with 3.9.13. Both versions threw the same error. Not sure this is real to be honest, and that is why I want to try it.

Comment: I did not get any error on Python 3.10.4. Maybe you can try with that one.

Comment: If this is legal, it is related to [pep 614](https://peps.python.org/pep-0614/).

Comment: How exactly were you running this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code works with Python version 3.9+. After running it with the newer python versions, the output will be `Hello World!`.

You can find a detailed description of how and why the code works in this article: https://mathspp.com/blog/the-most-obscure-hello-world-program